# C Code doesn't run all the way through on CMD but works fine on other IDE's Sorting Algorithms

Tags: c, sorting, cmd

The main.c file works fine in Repl.it, OnlineGDB, and Mimir. But I had originally written the code in VSCode but the code will stop running at random points, only on command prompt. Sometimes it will only run two lines, or all the way to 40,000, and rarely have I gotten it to run all the way through. It seems as though there is some sort of limitation on command prompt or my compiler. Attached is my main.c file and a screenshot of what my command prompt output looks like. Each time I run the code it stops at a random point. Jamila suggested adding system(“PAUSE”); before return 0; in the main function but that did not do it. I had Jon try the code through his command prompt and he didn’t have an issue either. So it seems it comes down to my computer. I have reinstalled MinGW according to the instructions from Intro to C but the issue is still present. I have an i9 processor & 16gb of Ram, so it shouldn’t be a hardware limitation. This is just odd behavior and I want to understand why it is only my computer that has this problem. I have also tried running it with the leak_detector_c.c but that makes no difference as well. Code works fine in Mimir, OnlineGDB, and Repl.it.

[IMAGE 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YF0MV.png)    [IMAGE 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYNYA.png) [IMAGE 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Jfdm.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAXVAL 100000

void randArray(int A[], int size, int maxval)
{
    int i;

    for(i=0l; i<size; i++)
        A[i] = rand()%maxval + 1;
}

void arrayCopy(int from[], int to[], int size)
{
    int j;
    for(j=0; j<size; j++)
        to[j] = from[j];
}

long timediff(clock_t t1, clock_t t2)
{
    long elapsed;
    elapsed = ((double)t2-t1) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC * 1000;
    return elapsed;
}

void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

void bubbleSort(int A[], int n)
{
    int i, j;

    for(i=n-2; i>=0; i--)
    {
        for(j=0; j<=i; j++)
            if(A[j] > A[j+1])
                swap(&A[j], &A[j]+1);
    }
}

void insertionSort(int arr[], int n)
{
    int i, item, j;
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
         item = arr[i];

        /* Move elements of arr[0..i-1], that are
          greater than key, to one position ahead
          of their current position */
          for(j=i-1; j>=0; j--)
          {
              if(arr[j]>item)
                arr[j+1] = arr[j];
              else
                break;

          }
          arr[j+1] = item;
    }
}

void merge(int arr[], int l, int m, int r)
{
    int i, j, k;
    int n1 = m - l + 1;
    int n2 =  r - m;

    /* create temp arrays */
    int *L = (int*) malloc(n1*sizeof(int));
    int *R = (int*) malloc(n2*sizeof(int));

    /* Copy data to temp arrays L[] and R[] */
    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
        L[i] = arr[l + i];
    for (j = 0; j < n2; j++)
        R[j] = arr[m + 1+ j];

    /* Merge the temp arrays back into arr[l..r]*/
    i = 0; // Initial index of first subarray
    j = 0; // Initial index of second subarray
    k = l; // Initial index of merged subarray
    while (i < n1 && j < n2)
    {
        if (L[i] <= R[j])
        {
            arr[k] = L[i];
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            arr[k] = R[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }

    /* Copy the remaining elements of L[], if there
       are any */
    while (i < n1)
    {
        arr[k] = L[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }

    /* Copy the remaining elements of R[], if there
       are any */
    while (j < n2)
    {
        arr[k] = R[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
    free(L);
    free(R);
}

void mergeSort(int arr[], int l, int r)
{
    if (l < r)
    {
        // get the mid point
        int m = (l+r)/2;

        // Sort first and second halves
        mergeSort(arr, l, m);
        mergeSort(arr, m+1, r);

       // printf("Testing l=%d r=%d m=%d\n", l, r, m);

        merge(arr, l, m, r);
    }
}

int partition(int *vals, int low, int high)
{
  // Pick a random partition element and swap it into index low.
  int i = low + rand()%(high-low+1);
  swap(&vals[low], &vals[i]);

  int lowpos = low; //here is our pivot located.

  low++; //our starting point is after the pivot.

// Run the partition so long as the low and high counters don't cross.
  while(low<=high)
  {
    // Move the low pointer until we find a value too large for this side.
    while(low<=high && vals[low]<=vals[lowpos]) low++;

    // Move the high pointer until we find a value too small for this side.
    while(high>=low && vals[high] > vals[lowpos]) high--;

    // Now that we've identified two values on the wrong side, swap them.
    if (low<high)
     swap(&vals[low], &vals[high]);
  }

  // Swap the pivot element element into its correct location.
  swap(&vals[lowpos], &vals[high]);

  return high; //return the partition point
}

// Pre-condition: s and f are value indexes into numbers.
// Post-condition: The values in numbers will be sorted in between indexes s
//                 and f.
void quickSort(int* numbers, int low, int high) {

    // Only have to sort if we are sorting more than one number
    if (low < high) {
        int split = partition(numbers,low,high);
        quickSort(numbers,low,split-1);
        quickSort(numbers,split+1,high);
    }
}

void selectionSort(int arr[], int n)
{
    int i, j, min_idx, temp;
    // One by one move boundary of unsorted subarray
    for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
    {
        //printf("\nIteration# %d\n",i+1);
        // Find the minimum element in unsorted array
        min_idx = i;
        for (j = i+1; j < n; j++)
        if (arr[j] < arr[min_idx])
            min_idx = j;
        // Swap the found minimum element with the first element
        temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[min_idx];
        arr[min_idx] = temp;

    
    }
}

int main()
{

    int sizes[] = {1000, 10000, 20000, 40000, 50000, 100000, 1000000};

    int *originalArray;

    int* sortedArray;
    int i, j;
    long elapsed;
    clock_t start, end;

    for(i=0; i<7; i++)
    {
        originalArray = malloc(sizeof(int)*sizes[i]);
        sortedArray = malloc(sizeof(int)*sizes[i]);

        randArray(originalArray, sizes[i], MAXVAL);

        arrayCopy(originalArray, sortedArray, sizes[i]);

        start = clock();
        bubbleSort(sortedArray, sizes[i]);
        end= clock();
        elapsed=timediff(start,end);
        printf("Sorting %d values took %ld milliseconds for Bubble sort.\n", sizes[i], elapsed);

        arrayCopy(originalArray, sortedArray, sizes[i]);

        start = clock();
        insertionSort(sortedArray, sizes[i]);
        end= clock();
        elapsed=timediff(start, end);
        printf("Sorting %d values took %ld milliseconds for Insertion sort.\n", sizes[i], elapsed);

        arrayCopy(originalArray, sortedArray, sizes[i]);

        start = clock();
        mergeSort(sortedArray, 0, sizes[i]);
        end = clock();
        elapsed=timediff(start, end);
        printf("Sorting %d values took %ld milliseconds for Merge sort.\n", sizes[i], elapsed);

        arrayCopy(originalArray, sortedArray, sizes[i]);

        start = clock();
        selectionSort(sortedArray, sizes[i]);
        end = clock();
        elapsed=timediff(start, end);
        printf("Sorting %d values took %ld milliseconds for Selection sort.\n", sizes[i], elapsed);

        arrayCopy(originalArray, sortedArray, sizes[i]);

        start = clock();
        quickSort(sortedArray, 0, sizes[i]);
        end = clock();
        elapsed=timediff(start, end);
        printf("Sorting %d values took %ld milliseconds for Quick sort.\n", sizes[i], elapsed);

        free(sortedArray);
        free(originalArray);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In function `partition()` you comment *"so long as the low and high counters don't cross"* yet you appear to be able to increment `low` when it is **equal** to `high` and vice-versa. Is that intended?

Comment: @WeatherVane That doesn't harm, because then the condition `low <= high` becomes false, so the `swap()` will not be invoked any more and the loop not perform more iterations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer was wrong, but I don't delete it yet so I can reply to comments.

---

Another guess: `quicksort` & `partition` look like you assumed `low` & `high` both inclusive. If so, the first call should be

```
    quickSort(sortedArray, 0, sizes[i] - 1);
```

instead of

```
    quickSort(sortedArray, 0, sizes[i]);
```

Unlike all other sorting routines, this one expects the ending index, not the array's length as its last parameter.

Comment: That did not make a difference, and they do the same thing.

Comment: @WeatherVane You are right, my guess was incorrect.

Comment: @andrewmccarty27 You are right, my guess was incorrect.

Comment: @andrewmccarty27 Added a new guess.

Comment: nevermind, your a flipping genius. It runs perfectly now. Thank you so much!